# What do you call the person or character being spoken to in a poem or song?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, songs

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/43537) asks what to call the person who is speaking in a lyric poem. The terms "narrator", "speaker", "persona", etc. may be used to refer to the "I" in "Shall I compare thee to a summer's day," but what do you call the "you" in, for example:

> The way that you flip your hair gets me overwhelmed

"Listener" seems inadequate given that the "you" isn't necessarily listening or being addressed, and might be fictional.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: There's "addressee", but that might not be in the register that you're aiming for. Are the two personae in dialog? If so, "interlocutor" might apply.

Comment: Possibly the 'subject', as it's about them as well as being addressed to them?

Comment: Addressee is certainly very common e.g. [addressee](https://web.uvic.ca/hrd/closereading/glossary.html): "The person or thing (for example a tree, idea, or emotion) to whom the voice in the poem is speaking", [here](https://heavyfeatherreview.org/2012/11/12/who-is-you-identification-and-importance-of-the-addressee-in-poetry-by-jillian-m-phillips/), [here](https://academic.oup.com/book/10325/chapter-abstract/158063525?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

Comment: I'd accept *target* (a bit objectified) or *singee* (a neologism, but at least clear).

Comment: In poetry, "gets me overwhelmed" sounds *awful, truly*.

Answer (score 0):

Literally (or at least in ancient Greece) a lyric poem was actually a song accompanied by the lyre, going back to poets like Sappho and Alkaios from the island of Lesbos in the 7th century BCE.  These poems were often but far from always addressed to a god, person or even personified inanimate object.

So Sappho, in what is (tragically) the only of her lyric poems to survive complete, begs the goddess of love, Aphrodite, to help her in getting the woman she has fallen desperately in love with to love her in return.

Lyric could be used for all sorts of purpose, including political invective and even wedding songs.  So Sappho wrote wedding songs, presumably for the party at the end of the ceremony.  All that survives from one is:

> Maidenhead, maidenhead, where have you gone? / To which the maidenhead replies "I've left you forever, forever I'm gone" (or words to that effect).
> There is another extract, addressed to the bridegroom, which is not suitable for the discussion of language usage.

Keats, over a millennium and a half later, wrote an *Ode to a Grecian Urn*, in which the urn itself is the *recipient/addressee*.

Thou still unravish'd bride of quietness,
Thou foster-child of silence and slow time,
Sylvan historian, who canst thus express
A flowery tale more sweetly than our rhyme:
What leaf-fring'd legend haunts about thy shape
Of deities or mortals, or of both,
In Tempe or the dales of Arcady?

But the addressing a person or thing is not an integral or required feature of lyric poetry, or, of course, of songs. Morever, since discussion of poetry does not have to be poetic, the words *addressee* or *recipient* can do the job, prosaic as they are.

Comment: This is correct: https://web.uvic.ca/hrd/closereading/speaker.html